# NSAttributed string on main thread

Tags: ios, nsattributedstring

I can use this to get all attributes from nsattributed string.

```
- (void)enumerateAttribute:(NSString *)attrName inRange:(NSRange)enumerationRange options:(NSAttributedStringEnumerationOptions)opts usingBlock:(void (^)(id value, NSRange range, BOOL *stop))block NS_AVAILABLE(10_6, 4_0);
```

May I know it is possible to get on main thread instead of block as in enumerateAttribute?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not an asynchronous operation actually. The `usingBlock` is simply called synchronously as part of the call to `enumerateAttribute:` and on the same thread where you made that call. See the `usingBlock:` as an alternative for a `for` loop that execute.

If you are not on the main thread then you can use something like this to ensure that:

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
   [string enumerateAttribute: ... usingBlock: ^{
      // Code here
   }];
});
```